How to change a locally cloned git repo branch to track remote another/renamed branch?
I had cloned a repo with a branch named master but now it's changed to main. I renamed my local branch but git fetch gives an error:
└─# git fetch                                                                   
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master


git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main
